# User logon by using mobile number

Tags: login

I created a custom field `phone number` in user_meta table.
please give me some ideas.

Comment: Why all these types of questions are marked as offtopic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all get user by Phone no.

```
$user = reset(
    get_users(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'PHONE_META_KEY_HERE',
            'meta_value' => $USER_PHONE_NO_HERE,
            'number' => 1,
            'count_total' => false
        )
    )
);
```

Now check if Password matches with the user we retrived by phone.

```
if($user){
    if(wp_check_password($USER_PASSWORD_HERE, $user->user_pass, $user->ID)){
        // Success. User login credentials matched. Login user with `wp_set_auth_cookie`.
       wp_clear_auth_cookie();
       wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
       wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );

       $redirect_to = user_admin_url();
       wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
       exit();
    } else {
        // Throw Error. Password Does not Match.
    }
} else {
    // Throw Error. User not found with phone no.
}
```

For More info about `wp_set_auth_cookie` [Click here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie)

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)